# What is the proper way of putting text under/over some other text?

Tags: underbrace, text-mode, overbrace

Long story short, I have a sentence written in the middle of the text width via `center` environment, and I want to put some text under or over some of the words to explain how they are made up, e.g.

```
                     write + -ed
this is a sentence with written long time ago
```

I'm not extremely interested in a brace to be there, but if I had to choose, I'd like it like this:

```
                     write + -ed
                     \____ ____/
                          V
this is a sentence with written long time ago
```

I know of `underbrace` and `overbrace`, as well as of `_` and `^`, clearly, but they work only in math mode, so I was wondering if a ready to use solution exists in text mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using an `overlay` `tikzpicture`. You have `tikzmark` and `decorations` libraries just for this.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage   {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}

\tikzset{my brace/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,raise=-1mm,amplitude=2.5mm}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0.5cm} % for the overlay picture
this is a sentence with \tikzmarknode{a}{written} long time ago
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=0.7cm] (b) at (a) {\small\color{red}write $+$ -ed};
\draw[my brace] (b.south east) -- (b.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** To force the `tikzpicture` to be on the same page as the text, you can place both inside a `figure` environment. This way:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage    {lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}

\tikzset{my brace/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,raise=-1mm,amplitude=2.5mm}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[2]
\textcolor{blue}{Comment this line and see what happens.}

\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\vspace*{0.5cm} % for the overlay picture
this is a sentence with \tikzmarknode{a}{written} long time ago
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=0.7cm] (b) at (a) {\small\color{red}write $+$ -ed};
\draw[red,my brace] (b.south east) -- (b.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice but apparently this doesn't enforce that the `tikzpicture` has to be on the same page as the text with the `tikzmarknode`. I managed to have the former be typeset in the right position, but on the following page. Any idea if this can be worked around?

Comment: @Enlico, see my edit, I think this prevents the problem. And thanks for the correction BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. FYI, thanks to your suggestion, I've verified that putting the `tikzpicture` environment _inside_ the `center` environment keeps all in the same page. I'd say it's probably a more desirable solution, as the text is not meant to float around, and a `figure` could still float, even with `[ht]`, iirc.

Answer (score 3):

I did this for a friend a few weeks ago.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{annotated}{\par\linespread{1.5}\selectfont}{\par}

\newcommand{\xrulefill}{%
  \leaders\hrule
    height\dimexpr0.5ex+0.2pt\relax
    depth-\dimexpr0.5ex-0.2pt\relax
  \hfill
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\var}{smm}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \linespread{1}\selectfont
    \ialign{%
      ##\hfil\cr
      \textcolor{black!80}{%
        \scriptsize\strut #3\IfBooleanT{#1}{\xrulefill}%
      }\cr
      \noalign{\vspace{-0.4ex}}
      \strut#2\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence
this is a sentence this is \var{a}{one} sentence this is a 
\var{sentence}{pqy} with text \var{written}{writ+-ed} long ago
this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence
this is a sentence

\bigskip

\begin{annotated}
this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence
this is a \var*{sentence}{xyz} this \var{}{missing} is a sentence this is a 
\var{sentence}{pqy} with text \var{written}{writ+-ed} long ago
this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence
this is a sentence
\end{annotated}

\end{document}
```

You can use `\var` anywhere, but as you see in the first example, the line spacing would be affected in a bad way, so I provide the `annotated` environment where the line spacing is increased to accommodate for such textual variants (or notes).

With `\var*` a rule is added to cover all the material in order to better specify what the variant refers to when it affects more than one word.

You *might* modify so the variant does not take horizontal space, at the expense of clarity.

[image]